# Unset data based on key match

Tags: php, laravel

data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9962
            [value] => Amart
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => attrval_9962
            [value] => k
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9952
            [value] => Denim
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => attrval_9952
            [value] => l
        )
   [4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5788
        [value] => Grey
    )

   [5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21307
        [value] => Long Sleeve
    )

)
```

Above is the data that store in array, anyone know how to unset the data if the **attrval_** exist so that i want to unset the data id **9962**. so the data will look like below.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => attrval_9962
                [value] => k
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => attrval_9952
                [value] => l
            )
       [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5788
        [value] => Grey
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 21307
        [value] => Long Sleeve
    )

    )
```

Which mean that I only want to store the data which is attrval_ exists else will store back the default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($data) {
    return strpos($data['id'], 'attrval_') !== false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First get an Array which contain

```
$filtered =   array_filter($data, function($element){
  return strpos($element['id'], 'attrval_') !== false;
});
```

Then find the difference of both array.

```
$result = array_udiff($data, $filtered, function($a, $b) {
  return intval($a != $b);
});
```

Comment: the $result will still contain all the  data

Comment: i have tried this, as per your $data array , $result will contain only two records

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
$result = [];
foreach(data as $value){
    if(strpos($value['id'],'attrval_) !== false){
        $result[] = $value
    }
}
```